# Leaflet, customizing the layerswitcher

Tags: leaflet, layer-switcher

So i recently decided to switch my project from Openlayers 3 to Leaflet, mainly because i needed the layer switcher control.

I followed the example on the leaflet tutorial, [this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html) one to be precise and i was very happy with the result, however, i really need to "customize" the layer switcher panel, this one i mean:

[image]

I want to create my own custom bar and use this to switch the layers, same functions, just different appearance.

I mean, just create a div with radiobuttons/lists on HTML and use this one to switch the layers.

How would i go about doing that? Is there a plugin or something else that can help me?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please take the tour gis.stackexchange.com/tour Can you describe a little bit of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Just the example on the official leaflet tutorial that i posted, that's pretty much exactly what i did.

WHat i was thinking was just to create a custom panel/bar on my index.html, and use this one to change the layers, instead of the one the layer switcher has as a default.

Comment: There are lots of plugins to work with the layer switcher. Here are a few. https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-panel-layers https://github.com/chriscalip/L.UniformControl

Comment: Thank you, these are some great sources to look at. 
However, i was wondering, is it possible to have this not inside the 'map' object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very rough approach to adding a custom layer control outside of the map, using only basic html elements (div, checkbox, label, etc.), no built-in Leaflet controls or plug-ins

**html**

```html
/* data attribute will be used in javascript to know which layer to add or remove from the map */
<div id="layercontrol">
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-layer="cities">Cities</label>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
/* using absolute position here, just to show you can put this wherever you want */
div#layercontrol {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```js
// load the following on doc ready (e.g. $(document).ready(function(){}) in jQuery
// using the example here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html
// the usual map setup - but no need to set layers as in the example
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [39.73, -104.99],
    zoom: 10
});

var littleton = L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.'),
denver    = L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.'),
aurora    = L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.'),
golden    = L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.');

var cities = L.layerGroup([littleton, denver, aurora, golden]);
cities.addTo(map);

// use jQuery to listen for checkbox change event
$('div#layercontrol input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {    
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var layer = checkbox.data().layer; 

    // toggle the layer
    if (checkbox):is('checked') {
        map.addLayer(layer);
    } else {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    }

})
```

Comment: How is the 'layer' of the data-layer attribute referenced to the layer object?